# XMD data manipulation using sql query

Tags: xml, oracle11g

I have following XML data in oracle table:

```
<PivotSet><item><column name="ITEM">PID</column>
<column name="MAX(CURRENT_VALUE)">C009</column>
</item><item><column name="ITEM">Customer_Name</column>
<column name="MAX(CURRENT_VALUE)">XYZ Info</column>
</item><item><column name="ITEM">Backup_Frequency</column>
<column name="MAX(CURRENT_VALUE)">Every day</column>
</item><item><column name="ITEM">Version</column>
<column name="MAX(CURRENT_VALUE)">3.1.0</column>
</item><item><column name="ITEM">Patch_Details</column>
<column name="MAX(CURRENT_VALUE)">Critical Fixes</column>
```

I want to convert data in following tabular format:

```
PID Customer_Name  Backup_Frequency Version Patch_Details
C009 XYZ Info      Every day        3.1.0   Critcal Fixes
```

Please  suggest how this can be done.

Comment: You have that as data in a table, or as the result of a `pivot xml` of data in a table? Are you really trying to do a dynamic pivot of the underlying data?

Comment: The XML data is in a table and I want to create an sql query to display record in tabular format as above.

Comment: any help on above is appreciated